# how can i give a vector of struct as parameter in the constructor of a class c++?

Tags: c++, c, xcode, class, struct

my struct:

```
struct Nodo {
float x;
float y;
};
```

my class:

```
class TabuSearch{
    vector<Nodo> nod;
public:
    TabuSearch(vector<Nodo> n):nod(n);

};
```

my main

```
int num_ciudades = 30;
vector<Nodo> nodo(num_ciudades);
TabuSearch t(nodo);
```

I am getting this error on xcode:

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "`TabuSearch::TabuSearch(std::__1::vector<Nodo, std::__1::allocator<Nodo> >)`", referenced from:
      `_main` in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: That code doesn't compile, but you're quoting a linker error?

Comment: Don't try to fundamentally change the question.  Edits are for clarification and fixing errors in the explanation.

Comment: @BenVoigt Seems a bit mean, it was clearly was a typo...

Comment: @PeterSW: The difference between a declaration and a definition is fundamentally related to an "undefined symbol" error.

Comment: @BenVoigt it is clear it was a typo from the context that the code complied for the OP. If we actually want to help rather than score points we should accept the OP's edit and look into the linking problems.

Comment: @PeterSW: If she wants to ask a question about a different piece of code, she should ask a new question.  Rewriting questions that have answers tend to confuse all future visitors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That `TabuSearch(vector<Nodo> n):nod(n);` shouldn't have compiled.  You're only allowed to put a ctor-initializer list on the construction definition, not merely a forward declaration.

You almost certainly wanted:

```
TabuSearch(vector<Nodo> n):nod(n) {}
```

which has a body (albeit empty), and therefore is a definition.

---

NOTE: Since you say that `clang` allowed compilation to finish and proceed to linking, that bug should be reported to the clang team.  12.6.2p1 is pretty clear that ctor-initializer requires a definition, not a non-defining declaration:

> In the definition of a constructor for a class, initializers for direct and virtual base subobjects and non-static data members can be speciﬁed by a ctor-initializer ...

Comment: Anyway, I heavily would modify it to: TabuSearch(vector<Nodo>&& x) : nod(move(x)) { } and the call: TabuSearch t(move(nodo));

Comment: @oopscene: And then it would not be invoked by the code in the question, which does not pass an rvalue.  Take out the `&&`, though, and it would be perfect.